# Updates for Laravel Socialite after Google+ API shutdown, replacement?

Tags: laravel, api, google-plus, laravel-socialite

Since google announced that Google+ API will be shutdown permanently from March 2019, What changes should I do in my website which uses Google + API for login.
I disabled Google + API in google developer window, and was expecting that login would work since Socialite would be updated automatically. But it isn't the case. Do we need to update Socialite from our end ?

PS: Getting the below error once Google + API is disabled.

> Client error: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?prettyPrint=false` resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response:\n
>   {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"usageLimits","reason":"accessNotConfigured","message":"Access Not Configured. Google+ API (truncated...)\n

Comment: Please edit your question include the code that you have tried and explain any issues you are having with that solution.

Comment: Well, for this case I am not sure what code to put. This is generic piece of information that I need which solves the issue. I tried with "composer update" to update the project dependencies with no help from it.  I'm not sure of next step.

Comment: What version of socialite are you using? It looks like this was fixed in v4.

Comment: @abraham:  Looks like Socialite v4 works only with Laravel 5.7 .. im using laravel 5.6 ... Guess this the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either upgrade to Laravel 5.7+ or follow the instructions mentioned here:

https://github.com/laravel/socialite/issues/317#issuecomment-451169514

> You can require it with Composer by requiring `3.0.x-dev`

Personally, I plan to upgrade to Laravel 5.8.

Comment: True.. Upgrading laravel would be helpful.

Comment: Socialite has released  v2.0.22 and v3.3.0 with the updated Google driver. No need to use a dev tag or upgrade Laravel. https://github.com/laravel/socialite/issues/348